# SQL / PHP - query for DATEDIFF

Tags: php, mysql, sql, date

i am struggling to put these 2 queries at same time. i got some dates in my database. and i want to only select the dates that are 3 (or less) days old. the dates are in this format: `2015-12-26 01:32:52`

And if I have for example something from April this year: `2015-04-26 01:32:52` then it should obviously not be selected. I only want to select dates from past 3 days. But nothing happens. I dont know what I did wrong. Am I not supposed to separate the queries with a semicolon?

```
$sql = "UPDATE users
            SET newdatecolumn = 
            STR_TO_DATE(SUBSTRING_INDEX(REPLACE(lastlogin,char(160),' '),'C',1), '%b %d %Y, %T'); 

            SELECT * FROM users
            WHERE DATEDIFF(DAY,'2015-12-26 00:59:34', newdatecolumn) <= 3
            ";
```

Also.... How can I get the current date? this date `2015-12-26 00:59:34` was just an example. I want to count how many days ago `newdatecolumn` was. I tried add `GETDATE()` but still nothing works.

And I need to run this UPDATE query. Without it, the newdatecolumn will not work. I must do that before I select the data

Comment: You can't run two queries in one call, unless you use `mysqli_multi_query()`. Just do them as two separate calls to `mysqli_query`.

Comment: You can get the current time with `NOW()`.

Comment: is there no way to combine them? I've done multiple SELECT queries before, but never with an UPDATE.

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html lists all the date and time functions in MySQL.

Comment: So the WHERE should be: `WHERE DATEDIFF(DAY, NOW(), newdatecolumn) <= 3` - is that correct syntax?

Comment: The name if the function is `NOW()`, not `DAYNOW()`.

Comment: But otherwise that's correct syntax.

Comment: I don't believe you when you say you've done multiple `SELECT` queries in a single call from PHP.

Comment: Here is an example when I did multiple queries for another thing: http://pastebin.com/pG1UNfKS

Comment: I only see one query there. Subqueries are not separate queries.

Comment: Well a subquery then. Is it not possible to put this "UPDATE" and "SELECT" together somehow like this? I dont use the mysqli query stuff. Would that work with this PDO?

Comment: `UPDATE` doesn't return anything, it doesn't help to put the `SELECT` into a subquery. And you can't use a modification query as a subquery of a `SELECT`. What's wrong with just doing two queries?

Comment: So I split them into 2 queries now: first query was the UPDATE. I prepared it, and did ->execute(). Then I did the second query with the select. It seems to be wrong syntax? `Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()` - here is my code: http://pastebin.com/QniSkp0T

Comment: You have too many arguments to `DATEDIFF`. It only takes 2 arguments.

Comment: You should check for errors: `$query = $db->query($sql) or die ($db->error);`

Comment: I removed the part with `DAY` in beginning and it didn't work. It selected all now. I don't get it. Shouldn't it only select the ones from the past 3 days?

Comment: It works for me: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b08de5/2

Comment: Oh you placed the NOW() in the beginning., Now it works! Thanks a bunch! you're a god! ur a legend!

Answer (score 0):

You have to make separate calls as you are having two queries. You
 cannot separate them with a semicolon in a single call. If you are
 looking to get the date and time both, try CURRENT_TIMESTAMP or
 canonical function NOW().

Answer (score 0):

Try use interval syntax:

```
... WHERE datecolumn >= (NOW() - INTERVAL 3 DAY)
```

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you want this: (you do not need a new column)

```
// this will select all data from users where the last_login  is less than 3 days
SELECT * 
FROM users
WHERE TIMESTAMPDIFF(DAY,last_login,NOW()) <= 3;
```

In case you dont care about the time but only the date use this (instead of )

```
SELECT * 
FROM users
WHERE TIMESTAMPDIFF(DAY,DATE_FORMAT(last_login,'%Y-%m-%d'),DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),'%Y-%m-%d')) <= 3;
```

I'm not a mysqli guy but PDO, not sure if mysqli_multi_query function will return the last row set automatically

but in PDO it should be run like this

```
 <?php
$pdo = new PDO('mysql:dbname=something;host=127.0.0.1;port=3306','user','password');

$stmt = $pdo->prepare('
        UPDATE users
        SET newdatecolumn =
        STR_TO_DATE(SUBSTRING_INDEX(REPLACE(lastlogin,char(160),\' \'),\'C\',1), \'%b %d %Y, %T\');
        SELECT * FROM users
        WHERE DATEDIFF(DAY,\'2015-12-26 00:59:34\', newdatecolumn) <= 3;
        ');

$stmt->execute();

// it allow you to retrieve the data from the second statement
$stmt->nextRowset();

while($user = $stmt->fetch())
{
    // do something
}

unset($stmt);
unset($pdo);
```